# Map numpy array values to scatter points

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, data-science

I have an Numpy array of the size (size_x, size_y) holding different values. These values are a Gaussian random field and the size in both dimension is given.

Also, I have a Numpy array of the size (nr_points, 2) with an amount of two-dimensional coordinates. nr_points is the amount of xy-coordinates in this array and given.

The sizes (size_x, size_y) are different of the bounding box of all points given in the second array.

**How do I efficiently scale and map the values of the first array to the points?**

Here is a graphical sketch of the desired task.
[image]

Comment: Please show an MCVE. Randomly generated data with a fixed seed is fine.

Comment: You do the mapping the same way that it gets transformed into a heat map: you interpolate at some locations. Pixels in one case, scatter points in another.

Answer (score 1):

- *Normalize* the coordinate values to the range of the size of the field array which will probably produce *fractional* (not-integer) coordinates.

  - ```
    scale = (field_array_size - 1) / (coord_max - coord_min)
    scaled_coords = coordinates * scale
    normed_coords = scaled_coords - scaled_coords_min
    ```
  - coordinate x values should be scaled to the field array `x` dimension size
  - coordinate y values should be scaled to the field array `y` dimension size
- You can only index the field array with integers so you have two choices:

  - round the new coordinates to zero decimal places and *convert* to ints then use them as indices
  - interpolate the field array values using the new coordinates